# Is there any theory supporting the idea that writing with your non-dominant hand is beneficial?

Tags: brain-training, creativity

E.g. Could writing with your left hand increase creativity? Especially if the left hand is the non-dominant one. Could placebo effect also play a significant role?

Comment: Could you frame the question a bit more in terms of prior research? Why do you think this research exists? Why would creativity be enhanced by writing with your left hand as opposed to with your feet or mouth?

Comment: @Seanny123, The train of thought was: right hemisphere controls left side of body + the right hemisphere is linked to creativity (I know that this is not entirely true). After reading The Superhuman Mind, by BERIT BROGAARD, PHD and KRISTIAN MARLOW, MA, I've began writting with my left hand for a few days and then I've tried to doodle. Surprisingly, the doodles were pretty decent given the fact that my drawing skills were not even average before.

Comment: So I was wondering if writing with my left hand had anything to do with it, if placebo effect played a role in this or I've had these skills all along somehow in a latent state and they've began to manifest because of my enthusiasm and dedication. I have to mention that I am far from being a specialist. I am just passionate about the subject.

Comment: Do you understand why your question was closed? Do you need advice/guidance on how to improve it?

Answer (score -2):

Yes. It is beneficial. There is physical evidence. And it also can play a role in terms of plasticity.

Comment: Can you expand this answer? It seems you have an answer, but it needs to be backed up by sources and one-liners in general are frowned upon.

Comment: Sounds great! Could you present some references?